# number of non zero entries of a boolean matrix and of its square

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $A$ be a $\{0,1\}$ square matrix of size $n$.
Let $nz(M)$ denote the number of non-zero entries in $M$.

define $f_n(A)=nz(A)-nz(A^2)$. ($f_n$ is a function from square $\{0,1\}$ matrix of size $n$).

How large can
$$
max_A\; f_n(A)
$$
be?

I managed to show that $f_n\geq n-1$ by the following example:
Define a matrix $A_0$ in which the entry $a_{ij}$ is not zero iff $i<j$.

A reference or a hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can improve your idea for larger $n$ by changing $i<j$ to $i<j-1$ (that changes $n-1$ to $(n-2)+(n-3)$) or to $i<j-2$ (that changes the answer to $(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-5)$) and so on; the optimal choice is somewhere around $i<j-\frac n2$, which gives roughly $f_n\gtrapprox \frac14n^2$.

Comment: @GregMartin as an example, make element at even row and odd column non zero. The matrix has $n^{2}/4$ non zero elements but its square has none.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I would have accepted either as an answer